# Perform async search that returns ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, mvvm, async-await

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and Entity Framework 6 to build an MVVM Light WPF app. When the user clicks the Search button, it calls a `RelayCommand` which has been defined like this in the View Model's constructor:

```
SearchEmployeesRelayCommand = new RelayCommand(SearchEmployees);
```

The `SearchEmployees` method in the View Model looks like this:

```
private BackgroundWorker _worker;

public void SearchEmployees()
{
    _worker = new BackgroundWorker(); // use this to show busy indicator

    var dataService = new EmployeeDataService();
    _worker.DoWork += (o, ea) =>
    {
        SearchResults = dataService.SearchEmployees(SelectedColumn, SearchValue);
    };
    _worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (o, ea) =>
    {
        IsSearching = false;
    };

    IsSearching = true;
    _worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

The data service's search method looks like this:

```
public ObservableCollection<EmployeeViewModel> 
    SearchEmployees(string selectedColumn, string searchValue)
{
    var paramEmployee = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Employee), "e");

    var comparison = Expression.Lambda<Func<Employee, bool>>(
        Expression.Equal(
            Expression.Property(paramEmployee, selectedColumn),
            Expression.Constant(searchValue)),
            paramEmployee).Compile();

    using (var context = new MyEntities())
    {
        var query = (from e in context.Employees
                     .Where(comparison)
                     select new EmployeeViewModel
                     {
                         // Various EF model properties...
                     });
        return new ObservableCollection<EmployeeViewModel>(query);
    }
}
```

If I try to make the above method `async` and `awaitable`, with something like this:

```
return await new ObservableCollection<EmployeeViewModel>(query);
```

It gives this error:

> 'ObservableCollection' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'ObservableCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How do you make the search `async` if it's returning an `ObservableCollection`? Thanks.

**Update**: For the busy indicator to work, I had to make this change:

```
_worker.DoWork += async (o, ea) =>
{
    SearchResults = await dataService
        .SearchEmployees(selectedColumnValue, SearchValue);
    IsSearching = false;
};
```

And I removed the `_worker.RunWorkerCompleted` block altogether. There probably is a better way to do that, but this was how I got it working.

Comment: You need to read this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of approaches. First, you can keep your database access synchronous and just run it on a background thread. Note that `Task.Run` is a modern replacement for `BackgroundWorker` (I have a [blog series that draws parallels between the two](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/05/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-intro.html)):

```
public async Task SearchEmployeesAsync()
{
  var dataService = new EmployeeDataService();
  var selectedColumn = SelectedColumn;
  var searchValue = searchValue;

  IsSearching = true;
  try
  {
    SearchResults = await Task.Run(() => dataService.SearchEmployees(selectedColumn, searchValue));
  }
  finally
  {
    IsSearching = false;
  }
}
```

Alternatively, since you are using EF6, you can make your database query asynchronous and not mess around with background threads at all:

```
public async Task<ObservableCollection<EmployeeViewModel>> 
    SearchEmployeesAsync(string selectedColumn, string searchValue)
{
  var paramEmployee = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Employee), "e");
  var comparison = Expression.Lambda<Func<Employee, bool>>(
    Expression.Equal(
      Expression.Property(paramEmployee, selectedColumn),
      Expression.Constant(searchValue)),
      paramEmployee).Compile();

  using (var context = new MyEntities())
  {
    var query = (from e in context.Employees
                 .Where(comparison)
                 select new EmployeeViewModel
                 {
                     // Various EF model properties...
                 });
    var data = await query.ToListAsync();
    return new ObservableCollection<EmployeeViewModel>(data);
  }
}

public async Task SearchEmployeesAsync()
{
  var dataService = new EmployeeDataService();
  IsSearching = true;
  try
  {
    SearchResults = await dataService.SearchEmployeesAsync(SelectedColumn, SearchValue);
  }
  finally
  {
    IsSearching = false;
  }
}
```

You should **not** make `BackgroundWorker.DoWork` asynchronous; that will cause it to "end early" and prevent it from gracefully handling exceptions. BGW simply wasn't designed to work with `async` code.

Comment: Thanks, @StephenCleary. Is there a reason for the `query.ToListAsync()` and then getting a new `ObservableCollection` from that?

Comment: It's giving me trouble with the `RelayCommand`, which was a delegate method name with no return type. How do I change its return type from `void` to `Task` on this line `SearchEmployeesRelayCommand = new RelayCommand(SearchEmployees);`?

Comment: I think this solves the problem with the `RelayCommand` returning a value: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240042/commanding-in-mvvm-wpf-how-to-return-a-value

Comment: @Alex: Re `ToListAsync`, it's just split up to be clearer. Re asynchronous `ICommand`s, I have written [an article on the subject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn630647.aspx). If you want a quick fix, you can use `async void`, but beware that you should have a `try`/`catch` around the whole method body.