# Using Roslyn to parse/transform/generate code: am I aiming too high, or too low?

Tags: c#, code-generation, roslyn

*(What I'm trying to do is work around the [Application.Settings/MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/q/783934) problem by generating an interface and wrapper class from the vs-generated settings file.)*

What I'd like to do is:

- Parse a class declaration from file
- Generate an interface declaration based on just the (non static) properties of the class
- Generate a wrapper class which implements this interface, takes an instance of the original class in the constructor, and 'pipes' all the properties through to the instance.
- Generate another class which implements the interface directly.

My question is two-fold:

- Am I barking up the wrong tree? Would I be better off using Code-Dom, T4, Regex(!) for this, or part of this? (I don't mind a bit of extra work, as this is mostly a learning experience.)
- If Roslyn is the way to go, which bit of it should I be looking at? I was kind of naively hoping that there would be some way of walking the tree and spitting out just the bits that I want, but I'm having trouble getting my head round whether/how to use the SyntaxRewriter to do it, or whether to use a fluent-style construction, querying the source multiple times for the bits I need.

*If you want to comment on the MVVM aspect you can, but that's not the main thrust of the question :)*

Comment: Are  you interested in other-than-Roslyn solutions?

Comment: @IraBaxter, well, I guess if you've got something that's going to be 50% easier, I'd be interested for comparison's sake, at least.

Answer (score 13):

If your requirement is parsing C# source code, then I think Roslyn is a good choice. And if you're going to use it for this part, I think it also makes sense to use it for code generations.

Code generation using Roslyn can be quite verbose (especially when compared with CodeDom), but I think that's not going to be a big issue for you.

I think `SyntaxRewriter` is best suited for making localized changes in code. But you're asking about parsing whole class and generating types based on that, I think for that, querying the syntax tree directly would work best.

For example, the simplest example of generating a read-only interface for all properties in a class could look something like this:

```
var originalClass =
    compilationUnit.DescendantNodes().OfType<ClassDeclarationSyntax>().Single();
string originalClassName = originalClass.Identifier.ValueText;
var properties =
    originalClass.DescendantNodes().OfType<PropertyDeclarationSyntax>();

var generatedInterface =
    SyntaxFactory.InterfaceDeclaration('I' + originalClassName)
          .AddMembers(
              properties.Select(
                  p =>
                  SyntaxFactory.PropertyDeclaration(p.Type, p.Identifier)
                        .AddAccessorListAccessors(
                            SyntaxFactory.AccessorDeclaration(SyntaxKind.GetAccessorDeclaration)
                                  .WithSemicolonToken(SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.SemicolonToken))))
                        .ToArray());
```

Comment: Reassuring: whilst waiting for answers, I got to something pretty close to this, though it was a bit more verbose (I wanted to be clever and avoid statics, and private or internal accessors. Just out of curiosity, do you have any idea why it's `AddAccessorListAccessors` and not `AddAccessorList`?

Comment: Still working on this, but I wonder: might I not be better off using the semantic model here?

Comment: @Benjol I'm not sure what would you need the semantic model for, but it's certainly possible there is something in it that you could use.

Comment: I thought it might be a way to get away from some of the verbosity, but I'd have to try and compare to see. And now I've got something working...

Comment: Semantic model is a way to get semantic information about the code (e.g. what specific type does `Point` represent), it can't be used for code generation.

Answer (score 7):

On the question of code generation, my advice is to actually use a combination of inline code snippets (parsed using `CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText`) and manually generated `SyntaxNodes`, but with a strong preference for the former.  I have also used T4 in the past but am moving away from them due to general lack of integration & capability.

### Advantages/disadvantages of each:

#### Roslyn ParseText

- Generates arguably more readable code-generator code.
- Allows 'text templating' approach e.g. using C# 6 string interpolation.
- Less verbose.
- Guarantees valid syntax trees.
- Can be [more performant](http://blog.comealive.io/Syntax-Factory-Vs-Parse-Text/).
- Easier to get started.
- Text can become harder to read than `SyntaxNodes` if majority is procedural.

#### Roslyn SyntaxNode building

- Better for transforming existing syntax trees - no need to start from scratch.

  - But existing trivia can make this confusing/complex.
- More verbose. Arguably harder to read and build.

  - Syntax trees are often more complex than you imagine
- `SyntaxFactory` API provides guidance on valid syntax.
- [Roslyn Quoter](http://roslynquoter.azurewebsites.net/) helps you transform textual code to factory code.
- Syntax trees are not necessarily valid.
- Code is perhaps more robust once written.

### T4 templates

- Good if majority of code to be generated is boiler plate.
- No proper CI support.
- No syntax highlighting or intellisense without 3rd party extensions.
- One to one mapping between input and output files.

  - Not ideal if you are doing more complex generation e.g. entire class hierarchy based on single input.
- Still probably want to use Roslyn to "reflect" on input types, otherwise you will get into trouble with System.Reflection and file locks etc.
- Less discoverable API. T4 includes,  parameters etc. can be confusing to learn.

### Roslyn code-gen tips

- If you are only parsing snippets of code e.g. method statements, then you will need to use `CSharpParseOptions.Default.WithKind(SourceCodeKind.Script)` to get the right syntax nodes back.
- If you are parsing a whole block of code for a method body then you will want to parse it as a `GlobalStatementSyntax` and then access the `Statement` property as a `BlockSyntax`.
- Use a helper method to parse single `SyntaxNodes`:

  ```
      private static TSyntax ParseText<TSyntax>(string code, bool asScript = false)
      {
          var options = asScript
              ? CSharpParseOptions.Default.WithKind(SourceCodeKind.Script)
              : CSharpParseOptions.Default;

          var syntaxNodes =
              CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(code, options)
                  .GetRoot()
                  .ChildNodes();

          return syntaxNodes.OfType<TSyntax>().First();
      }
  ```
- When building `SyntaxNodes` by hand you will typically want to make a final call to `SyntaxTree.NormalizeWhitespace(elasticTrivia: true)` to make the code "round-trippable".
- Typically you will want to use `SyntaxNode.ToFullString()` to get the actual code text including trivia.
- Use `SyntaxTree.WithFilePath()` as a convenient place to store the eventual file name for when you come to write out the code.
- If your goal is to output source files, the end game is to end up with valid `CompilationUnitSyntaxs`.
- Don't forget to pretty-print using `Formatter.Format` as one of the final steps.

Comment: T4 templates can easily generate multiple files. I use an XML input to drive the generation of class files, its quite powerful. Its declarative but for generating boilerplate or repetitive code its very strong.

Answer (score 5):

I think Roslyn is a great way to solve this problem.  In terms of what part of Roslyn would I use - I would probably use a `SyntaxWalker` over the original class, and then use the Fluent API to build up new `SyntaxNodes` for the new types you want to generate.  You may be able to re-use some parts of the original tree in the generated code (for example, the argument lists, etc).

A quick example of what this might look like is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Roslyn.Compilers;
using Roslyn.Compilers.CSharp;
using Roslyn.Services;
using Roslyn.Services.CSharp;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var syntaxTree = SyntaxTree.ParseText(@"
class C
{
    internal void M(string s, int i)
    {
    }
}");


        }
    }


class Walker : SyntaxWalker
{
    private InterfaceDeclarationSyntax @interface = Syntax.InterfaceDeclaration("ISettings");

    private ClassDeclarationSyntax wrapperClass = Syntax.ClassDeclaration("SettingsWrapper")
        .WithBaseList(Syntax.BaseList(
            Syntax.SeparatedList<TypeSyntax>(Syntax.ParseTypeName("ISettings"))));

    private ClassDeclarationSyntax @class = Syntax.ClassDeclaration("SettingsClass")
        .WithBaseList(Syntax.BaseList(
            Syntax.SeparatedList<TypeSyntax>(Syntax.ParseTypeName("ISettings"))));

    public override void VisitMethodDeclaration(MethodDeclarationSyntax node)
    {
        var parameters = node.ParameterList.Parameters.ToArray();
        var typeParameters = node.TypeParameterList.Parameters.ToArray();
        @interface = @interface.AddMembers(
            Syntax.MethodDeclaration(node.ReturnType, node.Identifier.ToString())
                .AddParameterListParameters(parameters)
                .AddTypeParameterListParameters(typeParameters));

        // More code to add members to the classes too.
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting idea, to walk the tree and build all the bits in parallel... Now I'm torn between this and svick's suggestion. I'll have to try both!

Answer (score 5):

I am doing something very similar, and I am using Roslyn to parse the existing C# code as well.  However, I am using [T4 templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee844259.aspx) to generate the new code.  T4 templates are designed for text generation, and provide a very nice abstraction so that you can actually specify stuff that LOOKS like code instead of this crazy object tree.